# Insertar datos desde Visual Studio C# Windows Form a SQL Server

Tags: mysql

Este es el código para insertar información a la base de datos:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO scann (fecha, n-pedido, cliente, pedido, condiciones, precio) VALUES ('" + fecha + "','" + n + "','" + cli + "','" + ped + "','" + condiciones + "','" + pesos + "')", MyCon);
MyCon.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("hecho");
MyCon.Close();
```

[image: Este es el error que me tira. gracias]

Comment: te recomiendo usar procedimientos almacenado y parámetros tal como indica Cristian Torres, ya que el código que estas usando es propenso a inyección de SQL. saludos.

Comment: Te recomendaria que utilices una capa de mapeo, para las interacciones con tu modelos de datos, ejecutar consultas de esa forma es totalmente inseguro. Podrias probar con  LINQ to SQL Classes es muy intuitivo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: toma la consulta que te devuelve , pegala en mysql workbench y ejecutala, alli sabras que te falta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encierra el nombre de la columna `n-pedido` con  `back-ticks`

Así:
`n-pedido`

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta.Podrias indicar porque es la respuesta y dar un poco de contexto?

Comment: En realidad sí es una respuesta. No se si puedes leer el error que se plantea en la imagen, pues menciona que el error esta en el campo en cuestión, y el requiere poder hacer la consulta. Osea una solución.

Comment: Por eso pregunte si podias agregarle un poco de contexto. Pq si lo unico que le falta es agregar comillas pq los nombre que contienen algunos caracteres deben ir entre comillas, estaria bueno aclararlo. Si no, la cerramos como error ripografico porque faltan comillas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usa parámetros para hacer el insert.

Arias algo asi

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Tu Cadena de Conexión" )
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla(Nombrecampo1,Nombrecampo2) VALUES(@campo1,@campo2)";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo1",Textbox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campo2", Textbox2.Text);
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Registro Ingresado con Exito...");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error no se Pudo Ingresar el Registro...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta esta correcta.. sin embargo, aprovechando que AP escribio lo que hizo hasta ahora, no hubiera sido mejor que el ejemplo aprovechara lo que hizo AP? ;)